# By default Checked checkbox using v-model

Tags: vuejs2

Hi Guys I'm Newbie at VueJS,
Anyone who can help me about on getting default checked at my checkbox list

I'm using `v-model` so the `checked` won't work

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: What is your `v-model` referring to? What does a checked value represent? Where is literally any of your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the input to a truthy value using the v-model directive

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selected">
```

In your component data  (Updated based on @Phil s comment)

```
data () {
  return {
   selected: true, // True of false, or other truthy value depending on needs
  }
}
```

Then, depending on the value on selected your input will be checked/unchecked.

Note - in the documents it is stated that

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked, or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data
> as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the
> JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

Read more at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Comment: It's usually [best practice](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-data-essential) to have a `data` **function**

Comment: You are absolutely right @Phil - will update my answer.